# Disable package type on nuget

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-cli

Using dotnetcore cli the packages are being generated with a packagetype node, causing Visual Studio to not be able to install the package.
Building the package on Visual Studio does not generate the node, but on dotnetcore cli it gets generated in CI like this:

```
 <packageTypes>
      <packageType name="api" />
    </packageTypes>
```

CI steps:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "${{ parameters.name }} - Restore"
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '${{ parameters.projects }}'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.Config'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "${{ parameters.name }} - Build"
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '${{ parameters.projects }}'
    arguments: "--configuration Release --no-cache"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "${{ parameters.name }} - Pack" 
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    nobuild: true
    packagesToPack: $(ProjectsToPack)
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'NugetVersion'
    arguments: '--no-dependencies --force --no-cache'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "${{ parameters.name }} - Push"
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: nuget
    arguments: >
      push "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*.nupkg"
      -s "$(NugetFeed)"
      -k "$(NugetToken)"
```

How can i disable it?

Comment: If we have statement like `<PackageType>api</PackageType>` in csproj file or  we define the PackageType in xx.nuspec, this issue will occur. Please check these two points first .

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? What's the result if we add `-p:PackageType=""` to the arguments of your pack task? If the issue persists, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT hi friend, thank you for your support, for me that didn't work but i found that having a global variable "PackageType" would lead to DotNetCli using it internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out "PackageType" became similar to a reserved word when using DotNetCli, changed the variable name to "ApplicationType" to avoid having the package type in the nuscpec.

```
  Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=PackageType;]$packageType")
```

Comment: Well, glad to know you've resolved the issue, please consider accepting it as answer to help more members! Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce same issue in Build Pipeline.

For me, the `PackageType` will be generated only when I specify the `<PackageType>api</PackageType>` in project file(csproj) or I define the `packageTypes` elements in `xx.nuspec`.

> How can i disable it?

So I suggest you check if there's any definition about `PackageType` defined in your `project file` or in the `xx.nuspec` file in project folder. Find it, delete it and this issue won't occur.

(The 'api' indicates you or someone in your team define the PackageType in your team project, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/set-package-type), different from `Dependency` and `DotnetCliTool`, `api` is apparently a **custom** PackageType)

Apart from above, you can also try adding arguments `--no-dependencies --force --no-cache --configuration Release -p:PackageType=""` to your `dotnet pack` task. Using `-p:PackageType=""` in command-line can disable the behavior in my machine. Hope it helps :)